# How do I fit an image to the shape of this PNG image in CSS?

Tags: html, css, image, sass, png

How do I fit an image over this png image but keep the shape? in CSS?

I've seen there is ways to do this with SVG clip path but I was wonder if there was a quicker way by just setting it as a background image or something?

thanks, sorry if it's a stupid question.

[image: image shape]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is the purpose of mask:

```css
img {
  -webkit-mask:url(https://i.ibb.co/mBrmH0k/Mf15d.png) center/contain no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1079/200/200">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1069/200/200">
```

Comment: It' not only `-webkit-`. Firefox supports it native! (https://caniuse.com/?search=mask)

Comment: @Brebber I know and FF also accept the -webkit- version so I only use that one until Chrome support the non prefixed version