# How to create image fancy shape using css?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

How to create fancy shape using CSS and html5   , I have a section in which I would like to create certain shape using css

Here is jsfiddle : [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kpg4wyn8/2/)

```css
img {
  height: 145px;
  width: 145px;
  border-radius: 30% 70% 70% 30% / 30% 30% 70% 70%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/xSLLSKk.png" />
</div>
```

**And here are the expected results:**

[image]

> **Note: without using mask.**

Unfortunately, I am not getting the same result as expected, what do I need to change here to get exactly as the image above?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65255101/8620333 / https://stackoverflow.com/q/66736331/8620333

Comment: but those question talks about masking and svg why is that a duplicate qn ?

Comment: This is what you have to use for such shape. I will add more duplicates. In the mean time you can play with this : https://9elements.github.io/fancy-border-radius/#52.40.49.30--. (I am finding it's related duplicate)

Comment: @TemaniAfif I am using that link too but I was not able to get the same result as expected that is why I asked

Comment: and that's why I am giving you the other question because you won't be able to do it with with border radius. You need advanced feature. This is what mask or SVG are made for